# Programa não compila com erros diversos

Tags: c, sintaxe

O que está errado aqui? Não consigo ver o erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Main(void)
{
    int a = 9;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 0;

    int *p = &b;
    c = a/*p;

    printf("%d \n", c);


}
```

Comment: Nessas horas sempre ajuda mostrar qual é a mensagem de erro retornada pelo compilador.

Comment: verdade @hugomg

Comment: @drd0sPy Então, não quer [edit] a pergunta para incluir a mensagem de erro como o hugomg sugeriu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há três erros:

- A função principal deve chamar `main`  e não `Main`.
- Esta função deve retornar um `int` e não `void`. Alguns compiladores aceitam esta forma mas isto não quer dizer que seja correto usar em C padrão.
- o uso de `/*` é um início de comentário. Você precisa garantir que não tenha ambiguidade usando parênteses.

Código correto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 9;
    int b = 3;
    int *p = &b;
    int c = a / (*p);
    printf("%d \n", c);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/s5nllo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/owbftypr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Access.c).

Comment: Obrigado @bigown

Comment: Não Precisa Ser `int main` No Visual C++ 2013 Roda De Boa Como `void`.

Comment: @axell13 editei para esclarecer este ponto

Comment: Em vez de parenteses para evitar ambiguidade, também pode usar espaço em branco (espaço em branco é barato e torna o código mais legível): `c = a / *p;`