# Hello World em C++ não compila

Tags: c++, sintaxe

Estou lendo o livro *"Treinamento em Linguagem C++"*, porém está ensinando tudo errado. O `hello world` do livro simplesmente não compila:

```
#include <iostream.h>
void main() {
cout << "Primeiro Programa";
}
```

Segue imagem:

[image: Cópia da página do livro com o exemplo]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se realmente está assim o livro é muito ruim, jogue fora e procure um melhor.

Tem alguns problemas neste código

- Em C++ os arquivos de inclusão não levam o sufixo `.h` como no C. É nele que está a declaração do `cout` (os arquivos costumam ser `.hpp` mas na importação no código não se usa a extensão).
- As definições de função devem obrigatoriamente ter parênteses após seu nome.
- O retorno da função `main()` deve ser um inteiro.
- O `cout` precisa do seu nome completo, ou seja, `std::cout`.

Assim compila:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Primeiro Programa";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/k23v93). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sincfygi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/CallNamespace.cpp).

Uma variação usada quando o programa começa se tornar mais complexo (não que compense neste caso, apenas para mostrar algo muito usado):

```
#include <iostream>
using std;

int main() {
    cout << "Primeiro Programa";
}
```

Comment: Estou lendo a versão em pdf.

Comment: Aí não precisa jogar fora, só deletar :P

Comment: Vou fazer isso mesmo, livro lixo!!

Comment: http://www.pontov.com.br/files/cpp/roadmapcpp/ApostilaProgramacaoCppv045.pdf O pessoal também gosta do "C++ Como Programar" do Deitel (esse tem que comprar).

Comment: Vlw pela apostila, parece ser boa...

Comment: Por incrível que pareça essa é uma variação do primeiro exemplo do livro [How not to program in C++](http://www.nostarch.com/hownotc.htm). Se você está curioso, esse código vai contra as padronizações, mas parece com várias coisas que compilam (ou ao menos compilavam) em uma série de compiladores (ruins).

Comment: @Leonardo não conheço, mas pode não ser ruim, só muito velho, isso é código pré-padrão, uma época na história do C++ já foi válido. Particularmente não recomendo Deitel, muito gigante, enrola demais, não tão moderno. [C++ Primer](http://www.amazon.com/Primer-5th-Edition-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0321714113) pra iniciante é bom, [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) pra ficar mais por dentro. Os dos Stroustrup, criador da linguagem, também são atualizados e bons, ele tem livros que abrangem toda a linguagem, como voltados pra iniciantes também.

Comment: Tem Um Detalhe Não Precisa Ser int main(), No Visual C++ 2013 Roda Tranquilo Como void Odeio Isso Que Pora

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43252/101